# Use Nook Tablet in the UK

Tags: nook-color

I will be visiting the U.S. this month and I was thinking about buying the Nook Tablet from Barnes and Noble whilst over there as I am looking for a Tablet to primarily read books on but also browser the web and watch videos.

Two questions

Will the Tablet work in the UK when I get back? By "work" I mean will I be able to browse the web, watch videos on the device and read books that are already on the device?

Can you put your own books on there? I have a number of books already in mobi format, happy to convert them if necessary.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

1. AFAIK the nook tablet doesnt have 3g support. So country specific problems are not applicable. You can use wifi wherever you want.
2. With the kindle app or another app that supports .mobi it is possible. Otherwise you can use a program like calibre in your PC to convert them to epub.